# Positive limit of sequence vs. positive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_m\}$ be a sequence in $E_1$ that converges to $L \in E_1$.

a. prove that if $L>0$ and there exists $n \in N$ such that for all $m >n$ holds that $x_m > 0$

b. True or false? If for all $m \in N$ holds that $x_m > 0$, then $L > 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any ideas or have tried anything? Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hints: $(a)$ is true by definition. For every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists... How can we use this to imply $x_m>0$ for all $m$ greater than some $N$?

$(b)$ The answer is no. For inspiration, think about the sequence $\left\{1-\frac{1}{n}\right\}$ for $n>0$.

Comment: maybe your b's example is wrong?

Comment: Hence the emphasis on inspiration.

Comment: sorry my english is poor , my understanding of the (b) is if for all$x_n>0$ then $L>0$ and your example is true..?

Comment: @Xiaolang: No, my sequence is merely used an as example to get the OP to try to think of one on his/her own. In my case, all terms in the sequence are less than $1$, but the limit $L\not<1$.

Comment: yes your method is more useful to let the OP to think himself.Learned,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just consult the definition of limit

a.for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $n_0 \in N$ s.t. for all $n>n_0$ holds that

$$丨x_m-L丨<\epsilon \Rightarrow x_m>L-\epsilon $$

just let $\epsilon = L/2$ or $L/3$ and you can get it

b. consider the sequence $x_n=1/n$ and it's not ture